# Change metadata in bulk

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In Share, we can, file by file, change custom metadata from content models in the "Edit properties" section.

Is there a way of doing so in bulk ? So select multiple files and change the properties of all of them at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You ask the right questions from the end user perspective. Unfortunately Alfresco does not support to change metadata for multiple documents and does not have an API to support such a (understandably important) use case. Alfresco also misses a concept of smart filter methods for available actions on selected documents. The list of available actions in the doc list is always the same independent from the selected docs.

It would be possible to extend the Alfresco API and the Share UI for such a requirement, but it would not be a small effort, since an analysis of the changeable metadata would have to be done dynamically for the selected documents (backend API) and the Alfresco forms framework does not support this type of dynamic / virtual models (frontend API) to be rendered as a form for properties to be changed.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to create a custom action/webscript like we can do in folders, but in the Share section?

Comment: sure but unless you only have one fixed set of metadata which applies to all docs you still need a higher level api which checks which properties are available (intersection) for the selected docs to be modified to build the UI form for the action.